# Eclipse Auto-Correct Feature?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Is there a way to have Eclipse auto-correct certain misspellings? For example, I tend to type "System" as "Sysetm", and Eclipse catches it. However, it only tells me it's an invalid package, and I have to manually correct it. I'm hoping there's a way to have it be corrected automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've found no documentation or information about doing this. I know it can be difficult at times, but Eclipse doesn't let you directly "add" spellings to it's local dictionary, which is something that you cannot edit.

Comment: Would it be possible to develop a plugin for the purpose?